# Sorting two non-adjacent columns without affecting any other column

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting

I have two different columns on Excel. 
I want to create a script that will sort Column F, (Have a header) and will sort Column B based on where Column F's sort worked out. **(Without affecting any other columns however!)**

So if I have

```
    ColB       ColF
 1. Cat        2
 2. Mouse      1
 3. Dog        3
```

The sort will give me

```
    ColB       ColF
 1. Mouse        1
 2. Cat          2
 3. Dog          3
```

How can I do this? 
I tried recording a macro, (or just plain up trying to sorting it with the two columns clicked and the sort button), but I get an error saying *"The command cannot be performed with multiple selections, Click a single range and try again"*

Comment: Exact duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570650/sort-two-columns-excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570650/sort-two-columns-excel)

Comment: Had a friend tell me this was a better spot to ask the question, so I did :/

Comment: I think there aren't any low-effort, non-VBA solutions forthcoming, so maybe it would help if you start a step farther back and describe *why* you're trying to do this. There may be a better way of going forward that doesn't require sorting in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect there must be a better way to accomplish whatever it is you want to do by sorting these columns, but here is a VBA solution that will do exactly what you asked for. Beware this code assumes there are no blank cells in the ranges you want to sort. Please leave a comment if this is a problem, because it will be pretty easy to fix.

```vb
Sub nonadjacentsort()
Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rngTmp As Range, s1 As Worksheet, tmpS As Worksheet
Dim tmpArr1() As Variant, tmpArr2() As Variant
Dim i As Long
Set s1 = ActiveSheet
'Set Ranges to sort.  This assumes there are no blanks in your data.
Set rng1 = s1.Range("B1", Range("B1").End(xlDown))
Set rng2 = s1.Range("F1", Range("F1").End(xlDown))
'Load first column into temporary array
tmpArr1 = rng1.Value
'Load data into larger array that will hold both columns
ReDim tmpArr2(1 To UBound(tmpArr1, 1), 1 To 2) As Variant
For i = 1 To UBound(tmpArr1, 1)
    tmpArr2(i, 1) = tmpArr1(i, 1)
Next i
'Load second column into temporary array
Erase tmpArr1
tmpArr1 = rng2.Value
'Load second column into larger array
For i = 1 To UBound(tmpArr1, 1)
    tmpArr2(i, 2) = tmpArr1(i, 1)
Next i
Erase tmpArr1
'Add new sheet and print two columns there together.
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set tmpS = Sheets.Add
Set rngTmp = tmpS.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(tmpArr2, 1), 2)
rngTmp = tmpArr2
Erase tmpArr2
'Sort by second column (Column F of original data)
rngTmp.Sort rngTmp.Cells(1, 2), xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
'Load sorted data into array and then overwrite columns on original data
tmpArr1 = rngTmp.Columns(1).Value
rng1 = tmpArr1
Erase tmpArr1
tmpArr1 = rngTmp.Columns(2).Value
rng2 = tmpArr1
Erase tmpArr1
'Delete temporary sheet.
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
tmpS.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this script! 
It gave me a good starting point to complete my project :D
I really appreaciate the extra text you added into it to point out how it works, will learn a lot from that!